# Coworker using the wrong title on resume

Tags: resume, email, title

My coworker has a Junior software developer title given by our company yet I saw him wrote that he is a junior software engineer on his resume. All he does on the job is to write code and create integration + unit tests for our endpoints. He did not do any design since I'm doing the design, so he is not fit for this title. How do I text/email him that what he is doing is unethical?

Comment: What is unethical about it?

Comment: Did he give you a copy of his resume to preview ? Or did he post his resume on a public website such as LinkedIn, and you happen to view his resume by chance ?

Comment: @Kilisi because this is not the title that the company gave him

Comment: @Job_September_2020 I viewed it on his portfolio site

Comment: Is he aware that there is a difference between "software engineers" and "software developers" at your company ? In many companies, both positions are the same while in some other companies, they may have 2 different roles.

Comment: Once, I knew a tester who posted on his LinkedIn profile that he concurrently worked in a "Dual Role: Senior Manger, and tester", which was totally false. But, I simply ignored that since it was none of my business.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 in our company, the swe title is people who participate in feature desgin meetings, write.implementation, and work with SDLC while he only works with half of the stuff on SDLC

Comment: I'm a network engineer, and thats what I put on my resume, but I've never had Network Engineer' as a job title.

Comment: What business is it if yours?

Comment: *"in our company, the swe title is people who..."* @Noom57 Sure, but does **he** know that? More importantly, is anyone outside your company who looks at his portfolio site going to know that?

Comment: @BSMP  yes, i understand. I should just mind my own business instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Job titles are company specific and can be anything. They can even be unrelated to the persons duties.

But in any case, it's your colleagues resume, you have no business getting involved with it. Many resumes I have seen over the years were part half truths and fantasy. It's not a legal document. It's a marketing document.

Comment: +1 for agreement but really for “half truths and fantasy.”

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand where is the problem? For most people software developer and software engineer are exactly the same jobs. I think your company is unusual in their approach and I don't think any recruiters or hiring managers will notice any difference between the two job titles.